# ireport raise error "ireport raise error:org:postgresql.util.PSQLException: error function regexp_split_to_table not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

in `ireport query` it raise error

> ireport raise error:org:postgresql.util.PSQLException: error function
>   regexp_split_to_table not exist

i am working in ireport 5.6.0 ubuntu.

> error:org:postgresql.util.PSQLException: error function
>   regexp_split_to_table not exist

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** SQL query that generates that error. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)